# What is the Route Details -> Description entity?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

In "Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations - Supply Chain", I am trying to find the entity name and its attributes that correlate with this:

[image]

`Route details -> Description -> (Type, Description)`

I have done OData queries against a number of different route-operations related entities and I cannot find where those 2 attributes live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this over on the [Microsoft forum](https://community.dynamics.com/365/supply-chain-management/f/dynamics-365-supply-chain-management-forum/458227/what-is-the-route-details---description-entity/1255343). It turns out that writing to `Route Details -> Type, Description` is not a straightforward thing. Those 2 attributes are actually fields on the `DocuRef` table in F&O and it appears that there is no publicly exposed entity for that. And thus the fields cannot be populated via `OData` calls. So I have been looking into building an X++ function in the web service endpoint layer of the F&O model.